# Webpack 2.2.0 with Module.noParse doesn't transpile 'require' of externals

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I'm moving from Webpack `1.x` to `2.x` and faced trouble. I would like to have all my vendor's libs be ignored by Webpack, because I prepared them by gulp.

In `webpack.config.js` I have `module.noParse` like:

```
noParse: /react|react-dom|redux|react-redux|lodash/
```

And I have `externals` section:

```
externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'redux': 'Redux',
    'react-redux': 'ReactRedux',
    'lodash': '_',
}
```

So, in Webpack `1.x` it works perfectly, but version `2.2.0` gives:

```
var _react = require('react');

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`
```

If I delete the `noParse` rule, webpack will include vendors in package and everything will be wrapped with `var react = webpack_require` and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Webpack 2** is stricter than its predecessor. It's hinting to you that you're likely misconfiguring it.

- [`noParse`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#module-noparse) by design throws if you try to use it on a library containing `require` and other module calls.
- [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals) tells the bundler not to step into external packages but instead replace the imports of them with a global variable.

Therefore, `externals` is all you need.

---

#### Cleaner approach

I'd recommend dropping the `gulp` task altogether and move your `react` / `lodash` bundling into a Webpack vendor chunk. Use the [`expose-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader) to export the modules on global window variables.

The following config should do it:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "vendor": [
      "expose-loader?React!react",
      "expose-loader?ReactDOM!react-dom",
      "expose-loader?Redux!redux",
      "expose-loader?ReactRedux!react-redux",
      "expose-loader?_!lodash"
    ],
    "app": "./app/index.js"
  },
  externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'redux': 'Redux',
    'react-redux': 'ReactRedux',
    'lodash': '_',
  },
  "plugins": [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: "vendor", minChunks: Infinity }))
  ],
  /* other options... */
}
```

<sup>Ensure you `npm i -D expose-loader` and add a script to your page with `src` attribute set to url of `vendor.js`</sup>